# C# MVP - method call

Tags: c#, mvp

I'm trying to wrap my mind around the MVP pattern used in a C#/Winforms app. create a simple form which loads folders and files in a listivew.

IDiffView.cs

```
 public interface IDiffView
{
    string SourceFolderPath{ get; set; }
    string RemoteFolderPath{ get; set; }
    string GetFolderPath();
    void PopulateSourceDirectory(IEnumerable<string> dirs);
}
```

in MainForm I have this below implementation for PopulateSourceDirectory().

MainForm.cs

```
 #region IDiffView Members
 public void PopulateSourceDirectory(IEnumerable<string> dirs)
    {
        foreach (var directory in dirs)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Group = lstViewSource.Groups[0];
            item.Text = Path.GetFileName(directory);
            **//item.ImageKey = AddDirectoryIcon();**
            item.Tag = directory;

            lstViewSource.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item });
        }
    }
#endregion
```

Here I little confused how to call method for assigning the image key for listviewItem ie **AddDirectoryIcon()** . 
Whether I should keep AddDirecotryICon() with MainForm.cs class, or should I  move to presenter or do I need to define it in IDiffView.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the PopulateSourceDirectory to be something like this:

```
public class ImageDirectory
{
   public string Directory{get;set;}
   public Image Image {get;set;} //or whatever type ListViewItem.ImageKey is...
}
```

then in your interface:

```
public interface IDiffView
{
    string SourceFolderPath{ get; set; }
    string RemoteFolderPath{ get; set; }
    string GetFolderPath();
    void PopulateSourceDirectory(IEnumerable<ImageDirectory> dirs);
}
```

In your form:

```
public void PopulateSourceDirectory(IEnumerable<ImageDirectory> dirs)
{
    foreach (var directory in dirs)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Group = lstViewSource.Groups[0];
        item.Text = Path.GetFileName(directory.Directory);
        item.ImageKey = directory.Image;
        item.Tag = directory;

        lstViewSource.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item });
    }
}
```

And in your presenter you'll have the logic that gets the directories along with their associated images...